# How can I pull a specific title from an array using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am trying to pull a specific title from an array using Angular.
Whilst I can use **ng-repeat** to loop through all titles and print these to my news listing webpage, I only wish to pull the first heading in my array for the news details page. Do I need to use the ng-repeat or can I use something different?

I have tried using number:0 as well as json:0.

```
$scope.newsListings = [
    {
    title: "Why cooking is great";
    },
    {
    title: "Windsurfing is fun";
    }
];


<div ng-controller="primaryController">
    <article>
        <div ng-repeat="item in newsListings | json:0">
            <h1>{{item.title }}</h1>
            <p class="synopsis">{{item.synopsis}}</p>
        </div>
    <article>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not [JSON](http://json.org). _"JSON is a textual, language-indepedent data-exchange format, much like XML, CSV or YAML."_ - [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation). `newListings` is just an array of _objects_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show only one item, you can omit the `ng-repeat` part as you want only one item from your array. You need just to use index.

```
<div ng-controller="primaryController">
    <article>
        <div>
            <h1>{{ newsListings[0].title }}</h1>
            <p class="synopsis">{{ newsListings[0].synopsis }}</p>
        </div>
    <article>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing. I have spent 2 hours trying to figure it out. Thank you so much. I now understand.

Comment: Is there a way of getting the data by ID rather than index position?

Comment: Show your complete data. You can use a method such `find` to find by condition

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use ng-model for this with a first element of array if you need 2 way binding as well (for inputs of course). For other purposes you can use just index.

```
<div ng-controller="primaryController">
<article>
    <div>
       <input type="text" ng-model="newsListings[0].title" />
    </div>
    <div ng-bind="newsListings[0]">
        <h1>{{newsListings[0].title }}</h1>
        <p class="synopsis">{{newsListings[0].synopsis}}</p>
    </div>
<article>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean when there is a search input?

Comment: Yes if you need a form or a way to update model from HTML view.

Comment: Oh OK. Thank you Mirko, very kind.